# Importing RSS feed with images in drupal

Tags: drupal, rss, drupal-modules

Im looking to import a RSS feed from a car site into my drupal site with images from that site, i dont have a slightest clue about how to do that. Any help will be much appreciated.
This is the link for that RSS feed (http://www.carbuzz.com/rss/news.xml)

Answer (score 0):

check this two modules they will help you..
http://drupal.org/project/feeds
http://drupal.org/project/feed_import

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use the [Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds), as Soni Kishan has mentioned, to import the images and other pieces of content. Feeds should have everything you need (supports RSS) so it's not worth checking out the Feed Import module (doesn't support RSS).

[Mustardseed Media](http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode55) has a great tutorial on how to use the module (a little less than 12 min). I also currently use the Feeds module to fetch prices from online stores and update my db, and it works flawlessly!